# Replacing SD card with Flash Memory Chip

Tags: stm32, nand-flash

I have a design in which MicroSD card is used for Logging and critical system information files.
Logging: text file of few MB. Max 16MB.
System Information: File format is xml and size is around 200KB. Worst case file size is 1MB. We support  keeping 50 file in memory.

The design has STM32 microcontroller with TCP/IP communication. Hosting FAT file system in SD card. The file system is accessible through FTP.

Now i would like to replace SDCard with Flash memory chip. NAND flash memory with parallel interface. I agree SDCard is flexible but we have decided to go with flash chip for security reasons.

At the same time i want to have log file accessible through FTP. The idea is partition the NAND flash memory. Mount file system on Log partition and make accessible through FTP. The other partition should support raw access.

The question is,
Is NAND Flash memory good option to replace SD card
Is FAT file system good option for NAND Flash memory

Thanks

Comment: SD card internally is using NAND flash.. so whatever file system is being used on it, it is equally "good"

Comment: Consider eMMC. There's a good chance you're using your SD card in MMC mode anyway, so eMMC would give you exactly the same interface, except soldered on (not removable).

Comment: FWIW, FAT is the least reliable FS out there. Consider one of the [Flash File Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_file_system) instead

Comment: Can solder chips but it's not hard to remove and read them. If security matters, should really be using encryption.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks. does windows recognize Flash File System

Comment: @hobbs thanks for suggestion. seems eMMC is a good alternative..

Comment: If you're accessing it over FTP it doesn't matter if Windows recognizes the filesystem you use. FTP doesn't 'expose' the filesystem in that way.

Comment: But whatever filesystem you think of using on 'raw' NAND flash, make sure you don't ignore 'wear levelling' which prevents you from wearing out one spot in the Flash chip.

Comment: FTP is a network protocol. Your STM32 firmware will read the files from the FS and "translate" them to FTP. So it is your firmware who needs to "recognize" the file system.

Comment: @brhans thanks for clarification

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks once again for details and clarification.